# Matching Game - setCard method

Tags: java, arraylist

Trying to create a **method** which accepts a 'number' and then using that number, it goes into a global `arraylist <string>` and changes the icon for location 'number' to a certain icon using a series of if-else statements.

the problem is i don't know how to call on the location.

without a method, i'd code it like this;

```
card1.seticon(a);
```

and i'd do that manually for all if-else statements and for all the items in the `arraylist`.

how do i make it dynamic so that the number after 'card' is constantly changing in the same method?

this is my method so far & i want to **replace the ones so with a variable or something that is dynamic**:

```
 public void setCards(int cardNumber) { 
        String temp = cards.get(cardNumber);
        switch (temp) {
            case "0":
                card1.setIcon(a);
                break;
            case "1":
                Card1.setIcon(b);
                break;
            case "2":
                Card1.setIcon(c);
                break;
            case "3":
                Card1.setIcon(d);
                break;
            case "4":
                Card1.setIcon(e);
                break;
            case "5":
                Card1.setIcon(f);
                break;
            case "6":
                Card1.setIcon(g);
                break;
                case "7":
                Card1.setIcon(h);
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: _Never_ do this. First of all, forget switch-case statements for good. Use a `Map<Key, Value>` instead or any other form  of polymorphism that applies. Also, globals are the root evil. Forget them as well. Here, it is not 100% percent clear to me what your intention is. Although they're not really for the complete beginner, I'd highly recommend you two readings:  **[#1](http://amzn.com/0132350882)**, **[#2](http://amzn.com/1932394850)**, **[#3](http://amzn.com/0321146530)**

Comment: ...The #1 book will give you lots of hints on how to solve problems like your question _"how do i make it dynamic so that..."_.
Considering _"trying to create a method which accepts a 'number' and then using that number, ... (!!!) changes the icon for location 'number' to a certain icon"_, you could use a `Map<String, Card>` and then issue `cards.get(id).setIcon(icons.get(id))`, completely omitting the "cardNumber" part as you probably don't need it. However, I'm not sure about your goals... PS.: !!! = don't place implementation details in your requirements. Describe WHAT to do, not HOW.

Answer (score 1):

Create an inheritance tree for all your instances.

```
abstract class Card {
    protected String icon;

    public Card(String icon) {
         this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
         return this.icon;
    }
}
```

Here is an example of subclass:

```
class CardA extends Card {
   public CardA() {
        super("Icon A");
   }
}
```

Do something like that with all of your cards. After that you can do:

```
List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
cardList.add(new CardA());
cardList.add(new CardB());
```

and lets say you want to iterate it:

```
for(Card card : cardList) {
    System.out.println(card.getIcon());
}
```

That will print:

```
 Icon A
 Icon B
```

As you see, with this procedure you can create and add any subclass and you don't have to modify  previous created classes.

Comment: Why would you create subclasses for cards that all have the very same behavior? That `Card` class without the `abstract` keyword seems fit, although if the icon is meant to change according to some logic, a setter method should be introduced as well.

Comment: I assumed that icon isn't only difference. Various types of cards could also have different behavior (I know the author didn't mention that). With this approach @sdx can easily implement other things in polimorfic way. Of course if the icon is only differing property, then a Map would be a better choice.

Comment: I see. My assumption was kindof the opposite: Even if not the icon is the only difference, the difference between cards manifests only in data and they share the very same functionality. But actually I don't have a clue what the context is for the OP's question...

Answer (score 0):

build a `Map<String, Icon>`, key is `"0", "1"..."7", "whatever"`, values are `icon a, b, c...h..anyIcon`

then you just `card1.setIcon(map.get(cards.get(cardNumber)))`

(Validation was omitted in above line.)